# Updating Flot displayed data

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm using Flot with jQuery to display a graph. I want to update some information on the graph and then re-plot it. I can see that I can use `plot.getOptions().yaxes[0].max` for example to update the y-axis max value and have got that to work but I'm using a plugin to add side notes to the graph.

I've used `getOptions` again to update the side notes data and can read the side notes' data, but can't see how I can get the side notes displayed data to update without completely re-plotting the graph.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide your current code? - this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to redraw anyway, generating a new plot with the new options is the simplest solution. You do not gain much by trying to optimize it (unless you want to redraw every second).

Comment: Hi @Raidri supports Monica, you are right, I was gettting into all sorts to progamming gymnastics as a result of trying to avoid a redraw, the legend and an overlay reporting cursor values was dissappearing, biting the bullet and accepting a total redraw worked out better.